# I am not able to make files using fs.writeFileSync() in Node.js, idk why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const folderName = process.argv[2] || 'Project'


fs.mkdirSync(folderName)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/style.css`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/app.js`)
```

This is the error I am getting when I execute:  
`node boilerplate.js Portfolio`

the folder "Portfolio" is made but not the files

[image: error]

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images, but as text.

Comment: The error message tells you that you are not passing any data to write to the file, but you have to. Please [read the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [the documentation for `fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options)?

It says `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])` – the brackets denote optional parameters and that means only `options` is optional, so you must always pass in `file` and `data`.

You aren't passing `data`, and the error message alludes to that with `undefined`.

If you want empty files, pass in an empty string as `data`.

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`, '')
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/style.css`, '')
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/app.js`, '')
```